# unity : Scene loading slow - 2D Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a super simple 2D Game. I have a play button on the main menu which takes a few seconds to load. Is there way to make it instantaneous, if not. Would a loading bar be useful in this situation ?

Comment: The only way to make it instantaneous would be to preload everything. In which case your main menu would probably be just an overlay over the game (and the loading time would occur when launching the game instead)

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks for the comment. I'll just make an overlay of the main menu then